# How to abbreviate HTML text in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a parsed text looking like "`some text <b>bold text</b>`". I want to abbreviate it on the page, but if the abbreviation stops after the first `<b>` tag, it won't be closed automatically. Is there any existing functinality for such abbreviation?

Comment: can you provide your controller and html code?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to get as a final result?

Comment: I want to get e.g. "`some text <b>bold...</b>`" In django which I previously used, abbreviation filter in templates did that out of the box, and thymeleaf's does only dumb abbreviation of text by letters.

Comment: The html code is just `<div th:utext="${getMyText()}></div>` Currently I do abbreviation in the code with string utils, but looking for options.